# ASP.NET Core - Starting the web server is taking longer than expected

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

I'm attempting to debug a ASP.NET Core web app using either the Web API or Web Application templates:

[image]
[image]

without adding additional code, etc. to the project.

I use IIS Express to debug the application and the following message is displayed

> Starting the web server is taking longer than expected.

[image]

After about 10 minutes of waiting, my processor utilization is less than 10%. It looks like the web server is not going to start with any more waiting, and so debugging is not going to start either. How do I get the web server to start so that I can proceed with debugging a .NET Core web app?

My machine environment is as follows

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview1-002702)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-preview1-002702
 Commit Sha:  6cde21225e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.10240
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

Comment: Try to delete your **Temp data** from your PC.

Comment: does that occur when using a different host e.g WebListener?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me the issue was the self signed SSL certificate install popup on start wasn't getting completed.

This is what resolved the issue for me.

My Setup:

win10
VS 2015 community
user is running as non admin
.NET core asp.net framework site/app
project configured to default to https using localhost startup
Default browser on startup - Chrome

Steps to resolve.

Start VS debug with IISExpress
VS hangs with popup stating "starting the web server is taking longer than expected"

Right click on icon tray in lower right main window
move mouse over IISExpress Icon and right click
Under the View Sites context menu that pops up select your https enabled site
This will open the window to your site and a popup menu asking you to trust your self signed SSL certificate will ask you to install the cert as a trusted SSL cert.

From that point on I didn't receive the startup hang

Comment: Also for me the solution was simple (HTTP/HTTPS): to not wait for the browser to be launched, and just go browse to the app's URL.

Comment: Works for me but I regularly - but not every time - must repeat the operation.

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue was just a port number, changed it and all was well.

Right click on your project in the solution explorer, and hit properties. On the left hit the Debug section and change the port number in the app url ie: http://localhost:4998. Save and debug again.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It solved the issue for me. May help others, as well.

Comment: This just resolved for me.  It is unclear why the port number would cause a hang, but as soon as I changed it, it worked.

Comment: Worked for me. Bizarre.

Comment: in my case it was due to using a vpn, as soon as i changed the port number and turned th vpn off it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer, if you were previously running .NET Core RC1, make sure you're not running into the problem outlined in [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Security.DataProtection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756390/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-aspnet-security-dataprotection) (try executing `dotnet run` from PowerShell). Then make sure you *restart Visual Studio* and it should all be working again.

Comment: doesn't really apply to me, but might be helpful to others +1

Comment: Thanks and yes, hopefully this saves someone else the same hour I lost.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I updated Visual Studio to Update 3 but didn't realize that I needed to update .NET Core as well.  I went to the following website and downloaded the .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2.  Once I completed the installation my projects starting working again.

[.NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows)

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IIS instead of IIS Express. It initially remapped the directory for me (successfully) and then ran into the same problem.

If I opened the browser and went to the correct location, it all worked fine and Visual Studio woke back up. Perhaps it is related to it not having permission or ability to launch the default browser for some reason.